# Magento Mobile SDK For Android and Iphone

Tags: magento-1.9, android

Recently Magento launched Mobile SDK for android and ios. This SDKS are only for enterprise edition. I would like to know if there any planning of launching mobile SDK for community edition?. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know but I don't think so.